# Capistriano set :branch

Tags: git, branch

In my deploy.rb for Capistriano I have the following:

```
set :branch, "2.3.5"
```

but Capistriano insists on checkout out deploy. Any ideas why and/or how to fix it? I'm using git as the SCM:

```
set :application, "Example"
set :repository,  "git@github.com:example/example.git"
set :scm, :git
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/example.com/"
set :branch, "2.3.5"
set :scm_verbose, true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set :use_sudo, false
set :user, "www-data"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is actually a bug. I opened a ticket for it](https://capistrano.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8716-capistrano/tickets/148) and [fixed it](http://github.com/pupeno/capistrano/commit/ccc9fe0c50934f1981aac0c2ffc7cacdf54ddc51) on [my fork](http://github.com/pupeno/capistrano).